# Can I use an 8GB stick of RAM on my laptop

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard

I am using a Samsung R730 laptop - http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/pc-peripherals/notebook-computers/essential/NP-RV711-A01UK-spec

It takes DDR3 RAM. I can't find any specific information on the motherboard, but in general, do you think it would be able to take a single 8 GB stick of DDR3 RAM? One 8GB stick is cheaper than two 4GB sticks.

I am running Windows 8 x64.

Comment: If this website is to be trusted: http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/laptops/277690/samsung-r730/specifications. Then the max memory on your laptop is 4 Gig. And I think you can only use 2 Gig sticks..

Comment: Yep, you can use 2 x 2GB sticks operating @1066MHz

Comment: @Alex OK, thanks. If you add that as an answer I'll set it as answered for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to multiple websites ([here](http://expertreviews.co.uk/laptops/277690/samsung-r730/specifications), [here](http://www.dabs.com/products/samsung-r730-pentium-dual-core-p6100-4gb-ram-500gb-17-3--windows-7-home-premium-64bit-laptop-7BSG.html)), your laptop motherboard supports up to 4 GB memory. You can only use 2 GB sticks (1066 MHz).

Answer (score 0):

I am solving the same problem now. I have a ntb NP-R730 with a 3GB RAM DDR3 1066 MHz. I know, it is possible to upgrade it up to 4 GB. However, in previews is written there is 32-bit Windows which supports up to 3,5 GB RAM only. But it is because of Windows, not because of hardware limite. If you will install up a 64-bit system, you can have up to 8 GB.

I had a same problem with another AMD notebook, where was everywhere written, it supports up to 2 GB (1 + 1). And I have installed 2 + 2 (4 Gigs) and it works. :-)